# What is the pH of cytosol? And plastids?

Tags: cell-biology, physiology, plant-physiology

My teacher ask this question, and I answered 7 to 7.4, but she said it's wrong.
I read a lot and found the same answer [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytosol?wprov=sfla1)
I'm here asking for confirmation of this and the pH inside & outside of the tilakoidal membrane.

Comment: What kind of plastid and which part(s) of the plastid? The [wikipedia article on chloroplasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroplast) contains relevant information ...

Comment: Thanks, that is kindly useful. Now, I just need a litle more confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The optimum cytoplasmic pH for performing physiological activities in
  plant cells is a neutral pH of around 7.2 to 7.4.
- The pH of apoplastic space outside plasma membrane and vacuolar pH is
  acidic ranging between 5 to 7.
- The thylakoid lumen is more fluctuating which varies during light /
  dark cycles and is highly acidic.
- The mitochondrial compartment and chloroplast maintains a basic
  conditions of about pH 8 for optimization of biochemical reactions
  occurring in these two particular compartments.

(Via: [https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpls.2017.02079/full#:~:text=Plastid%20stromal%20pH%20could%20only,cytosolic%20pH%20(around%207.3)](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpls.2017.02079/full#:%7E:text=Plastid%20stromal%20pH%20could%20only,cytosolic%20pH%20(around%207.3)).